# Split a Record and pass it to PublishKafka

Tags: apache-nifi

I have log files saved in the form 20171102-logs.log.

I'm trying to pass those logs to a Kafka topic, however they're too large for the parameters defined for the topic. The allowable file size can not be changed, so I'm trying to split the files. I've tried a couple of different things, but I'm having no luck. The logs contained in the files are in the following format:

```
{"date":"2017-11-02T12:33:55Z", "module":"java", "version":"1.8.0.45", "node":"node-name", "username":"user"}
```

Any pointers/advice on how I can split these files would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add few more lines from log file ?

Answer (score 1):

If your log files contain a single log message per line, separated by new-lines, then you can use PublishKafka and set the "Message Demarcator" to a new-line by pressing shift+enter as the value.

This will let the processor read the file based on the demarcator and publish a message to Kafka for each individual log message in the file.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply. I tried that, but now I'm getting a new error: TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 5000 ms.

Comment: I think that indicates a connection issue with Kafka, can you put the stacktrace in your question so we can see the full error?

Comment: @quiver13: Do you have correct broker url (hostname + port)?